# What happens to previously installed packages when I upgrage from Ubuntu 18 to 20?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

By previously installed packages, I mean the packages that are not included in Ubuntu by default and were installed by me, like node, nvm, Android SDKs etc. And what about other installed software like gitkraken, atom etc. Will I have to reinstall everything again if I upgrade to Ubuntu 20 from the software updater?

Comment: always take a bacup before you do an upgrade.some programs might be removed during an update other programs will be updated/upgraded,your files will not be changed during an upgrade.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 18 & 20?; so are you talking about Ubuntu Core 18 & 20 (thus `snaps` as nothing happens for snap based releases as the same snaps run regardless of version being containerized), or 18.04 & 20.04 (or *deb* based desktop or server releases) as that's more complicated.  Standard releases are *yy.mm* in format, *yy* is used for specialist releases.

Comment: I'm talking about 18.04 & 20.04. I understand snap packages will not be affected. But what about other packages?

Comment: They stay as-is.